# Help with stuck on boot

Tags: boot, filesystem

I just turned on the laptop and booted into Ubuntu, but what happened was that the screen remained the same. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to cancel all filesystem checks in progress but the loading circle is stuck too and not moving at all.

Please help, I'll appreciate any help

[image: The laptop screen]